# Invalid Enum value JAXB - Converts to null rather than throw exception

Tags: java, xml, xsd, jaxb, xjc

Using jaxb / xkc to generate a set of classes which relate to my xsd.

Specifically I have an issue with the following defined enum (from the xsd)

```
<xs:simpleType name="TEST">
    <xs:annotation>
        <xs:documentation>
            BLAH
        </xs:documentation>
    </xs:annotation>
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
        <xs:enumeration value="FOO"/>
        <xs:enumeration value="BAR"/>
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```

Now, if I pass C in as a value you would expect it to fail because of the following generated code

```
@XmlType(name = "TEST")
@XmlEnum
public enum TEST{

    @XmlEnumValue("FOO")
    FOO("FOO"),
    @XmlEnumValue("BAR")
    BAR("BAR");
    private final String value;

    TEST(String v) {
        value = v;
    }

    public String value() {
        return value;
    }

    public static TEST fromValue(String v) {
        for (TEST test: TEST.values()) {
            if (test.value.equals(v)) {
                return test;
            }
        }
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(v);
    }

}
```

Now in my mind it should throw an exception, however it doesn't. Probably because the fromValue method doesn't appear to be called anywhere? Why does it just set the value to null in this case then and how can i get it to throw an exception?

Thanks

Comment: This is indeed strange. I thought the generated code was also used by JAXB. How ist the conversion done otherwise? I have the same problem, because I want an error, if the value is invalid, but I don't want to do a validation for performance reasons.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try using validator to validate your input xml against schema.
fromValue method might get called in that flow. And you will receive exception.

Schema validation example is [link1](http://websystique.com/java/jaxb/jaxb-schema-validation/)  [link2](http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/12/jaxb-and-marshalunmarshal-schema.html).
Unmarshaller docs link is [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/Unmarshaller.html).